# Mongoexport: convert numeric date into ISODate

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

For the following dump:

```
mongoexport --db AegroDB -f "realizationStartDate" -c T_OBSERVATION --query '{"type":"PEST_INCIDENCE",'realizationStartDate':{$ne:null}}'
```

I have these results:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"55fc25ece4b05dccd6450478"},"realizationStartDate":{"$numberLong":"1443150000000"}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"565d9466e4b07bd3e9840e2a"},"realizationStartDate":{"$numberLong":"1448935200000"}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"565db72ce4b099bace4cb9de"},"realizationStartDate":{"$numberLong":"1448848800000"}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"565db9aee4b01d782a3bc5af"},"realizationStartDate":{"$numberLong":"1449108000000"}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"565dc17ae4b077cd2daa1ad2"},"realizationStartDate":{"$numberLong":"1449367200000"}}
```

How can I output the `realizationStartDate` field as ISODate in my dump? I'm using 3.0.7.

Thanks

Comment: `mongoexport` is a rather primitive tool. I don't think that it offers such functionality. You will likely have to write an actual program to query the database and format the values before printing them. By the way: What's the type of the `realizationStartDate` fields in the database?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Philipp. The type is `Int64`.